# How to Compare 2 datetime

Tags: c#, windows-8

i want to convert string to dateTime and then compare them, `i'm trying to compare 2 datetime stored in an sqllite database, but i still  get the error "no such fonction converttodatetime" here is my code:`

```
from x in db.Table<FicheTechnique>()
                    where Convert.ToDateTime(x.FirstDate) <= Convert.ToDateTime(newDate)

                    select x;
```

Comment: yes they are strings :   DateTime dt;
           dt = DateTime.Now;
           string newDate;
           newDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yy");, the message  is an sqlLite Exception: "no such function: todatetime" and the inner exception is null

Comment: Are FirstDate and newDate of type string? Could you specify the exact error message?

Comment: The Convert.ToDateTime method you are trying to use states that it always throws an exception. Try to do this instead. It will parse the string to a DateTime.    DateTime d = DateTime.TryParse(string);

Comment: i used that, it returns the error "no such function: Parse", also parseExact ..

Comment: I may of edited after you looked at it i meant the TryParse not the Parse method.

Comment: still the same prob my freind i tried all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

```
var data = from r in dt.AsEnumerable() 
           where Convert.ToDateTime(r["fld name"]) <= Convert.ToDateTime(newDate)
           select r;
```

Your problem is that you need to do `dt.AsEnumerable()` when you deal with data table. Your `data` will be enumerable row collection.

Full Example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("a");
dt.Columns.Add("b");
dt.Columns.Add("c");

dt.Rows.Add("1", "01/01/2001", "01:01:2001");
var p = from r in dt.AsEnumerable() where 
        Convert.ToDateTime(r["b"]) == Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2001") 
        select r;

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.ToList()[0][0]);
```

Works: `Convert.ToDateTime(r["b"])`

Fails  `Convert.ToDateTime(r["c"])`

Comment: Switch your solution i got this exception :String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: This is because the string you have is not in Date time format. YOu will never convert invalid string into date time. My solution is good. You need to make sure your strings in the field and in the `newDate` are date-type. e.g. "01/01/2001"

Comment: DateTime dt;
           dt = DateTime.Now;
           string newDate;
           newDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yy"); new date has the same format of firstdate

Comment: @MeriemBenMrad See my edit. Convert probably doesn't like `yy`  -what year is it, 2010 or 1910??

Comment: hello, i found a solution, i deleted the where and i made the compare into a foreach on the result list and it worked fine! thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

Basically what it means that the SqLite does not understand the function Convert.ToDateTime. This is deferred execution at play.

You can force the execution first before you filter the results. Only use if the table is not large as it will get all re records and then do the filtering.

Try the following:

```
from x in db.Table<FicheTechnique>().ToList()
                    .Where Convert.ToDateTime(x.FirstDate) <= Convert.ToDateTime(newDate)
                    .Select x;
```